# Update statement for skipped serial number

Tags: sql, oracle

there are 30,020 items in one table based on 30,020 serial number.
but i skipped 30,001th serial number 
i have to write update statement to fill that 30,001th item and total number of items will become 30,019

give me a suggestion for update statement ..!

Comment: Please show at least some table structure or something that makes us able to understand the problem.

Comment: `row_number() over (order by sn)` or `set sn = (select count(*) from T t2 where t2.sn <= T.sn)...`

Comment: Don't trust and depend on id's like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very dangerous to get hooked on gapless serial numbers, but if you must

```
update your_table
set serial_number = serial_number - 1
where serial_number > 30000
/
```

You'd hope to get number of rows updated = 19.